# How can I pass variable to register view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have used `php artisan make:auth`  it generates the register view and /register route. But I need to pass a variable to this register view:

```
<label>Region:</label>
<select  name="region" id="region" class="form-control" >
<option>--Select a Region--</option>
    @foreach($region as $reg)
        <option value="{{$reg->region_id}}">{{$reg->region_name}}</option>
    @endforeach                
</select><br>
```

Something like:

```
public function register()
{
   $region=Region::all();
   return view('auth.register')->with('region',$region);
}
```

But where is this kind of  method?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can achieve that in two ways.

### Overriding RegistersUsers

Laravel's default auth uses RegistersUsers trait on RegisterController to render view.
What you can do is simply override the function found on Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers
on RegisterController like the following

```
/**
 * Show the application registration form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    $region=Region::all();
    return view('auth.register', compact('region'));
}
```

Now above code will over ride the trait and use the showRegistrationForm from controller.

### Modifying Routes

When you do `php artisan make:auth`, it will add the `Auth::routes()` to your web.php file. Remove that and add the following,

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Now on route for register, modify the RegisterController@showRegistrationForm to RegisterController@register.

But do not use simply register. Instead use like getRegisterForm. Because register function handles the post registration logic.

Answer (score 9):

In `Laravel Auth:` it uses `showRegistrationForm()` method to create registration page. So we need to override that method.

Just Override the `showRegistrationForm()` method

```
public function showRegistrationForm() {
    $data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    return view ('auth.register')->withData($data);
}
```

And capture that data in registration page using `$data`...

Answer (score 0):

This function should be created manually in the `RegisterController.php` in the`app/http/controllers/auth/` folder. From this controller you can create any function but watch out for duplicate function used by the trait `RegistersUsers.php`.

Your function could also be written like that:

```
public function register()
{
    $region = Region::all();
    return view('auth.register', compact('region'));
    // This will send the $region variable to the view
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

write showLoginForm() function in your RegisterController.php file,
function name is `showLoginForm()`and it will overwrite laravel default showLoginForm() function.

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
   $region=Region::all();
   return view('auth.register')->with('region',$region);
}
```